# Understanding Counter-intuitive run time for a function in R Console versus Sweave

Tags: r, performance, function, loops

I'm working through a tutorial I found online about writing efficient R code. I worked on seeing the same result -- f1 should be faster than f2 -- but I'm seeing the opposite.

I've tried running the code in the console and in the RSweave environment and I get the different solutions. Of course, the timing is different each time it's run but usually f1 has a lower runtime than f2 in the console, but the opposite is true in RSweave -- I simply copied the code from into one RSweave chunk.

```
f1 <- function(x){
  return(log((sqrt(x*10^3))))
}

f2 <- function(x){
  a<- x*10^3
  b<- sqrt(a)
  c<- log(b)
  return(c)
}

start_time <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:1000){
  f1(1)
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
(runtime <-end_time - start_time)
R Console: Time difference of 0.065943 secs
RSweave: Time difference of 0.05585098 secs

start_time <- Sys.time()
for(i in 1:1000){
  f2(1)
}
end_time <- Sys.time()
(runtime2 <-end_time - start_time)
Console: Time difference of 0.1935871 secs
RSweave: Time difference of 0.05243397 secs
```

Does RSweave do something different that would yield this strange behavior?

Comment: I wouldn't expect *any* difference between those functions. 1000 iterations are far too few.  How do you know the difference isn't due to other applications running on the same machine, or the timer's accuracy?

Comment: I see the same behavior at 100000 iterations.

Comment: try 1,000,000 or more

Comment: That worked -- I ran it 10 times and see the expected result. Thanks!